Displaying Vue component outside div id="app"
Is it possible to display a Vue component outside of the <div id="app">?
I am trying to display some components in my Laravel blade file, but I need help figuring out how. Could someone explain how it's possible and, if so, how to do it? I have included some code below for better visualization.
@extends('index_vue')

@section('toolbar-top')
<div class="card">
    <example-vue-component> <!-- This wouldn't be rendered -->
</div>
@endsection

@section('toolbar-bottom')
@endsection

@section('toolbar-middle')
    @include('file')
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="card">
    <div id="app">
        <vue-component>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

If it's impossible, do you have any suggestions on achieving this? I have been searching for a solution but haven't found an answer yet.

First of all, you can output all the templates you need inside id=app element, so the whole app can have a common parent element. Or you can use as many apps aka widgets as you need per page, as long as they don't need to interact with each other. Or you can use a portal/teleport in case they need to

.
